# Redbor Kale having issues

Tags: raised-beds, brassicas, kale, leafy-vegetables

All of a sudden the outer edges of some of the redbor kale leaves seem to be drying. Anyone know why this could happen?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have they had a sudden exposure to very hot sun, or has your weather done anything dramatic recently?

Comment: We were in the 90s for a few days. I do have a row cover on it so it may be getting warmer under the row cover possibly?

Comment: it does look like heat damage to me - sunburn or excessive heat, maybe combined with too much moisture loss from the soil.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is related to some excessive and abnormal heat wave we had for a few days.  The plant seems to have recovered, except for the few leaves that got hit with the excessive heat. In hindsight I should have increased the water frequency or times during the heat wave.

Comment: Yes, I am in Zone 9B and our weather is pretty dry

Comment: I will try this next time I encounter abnormal heat